# How to fix "Page not found (404)" error ("Django tried these URL patterns... The empty path didn't match any of these.")

Tags: python, django, request, http-status-code-404, urlconf

As a newbie to Django, I encountered the same problem as many before me. I would appreciate if you didn't mark my question as a double immediately because I checked the fixes those old posts suggested but to no avail.

I was following [this](https://realpython.com/get-started-with-django-1/#projects-app-views) tutorial and have finished with all up to the heading "Projects App: Templates". Now when I start the server, at http://localhost:8000/ I get:

> Page not found (404)
>   Request Method:   GET
>   Request URL:  http://localhost:8000/
>
> Using the URLconf defined in personal_portfolio.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
>
> ```
> admin/
> projects/
> ```
>
> The empty path didn't match any of these.
>
> You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

This is console output when I run server:

> System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
>
> April 05, 2019 - 15:31:54
>
> Django version 2.2, using settings 'personal_portfolio.settings'
>
> Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
>
> Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
>
> Not Found: /
>
> [05/Apr/2019 15:32:01] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2042
>
> Not Found: /favicon.ico
>
> [05/Apr/2019 15:32:01] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 2093

What I tried, but didn't help:

1. restarting the server,
2. checking my code inside the files against the tutorial's [source code](https://github.com/realpython/materials/tree/d49c624500e4470107bb258642d2744eeeeefc5a/rp-portfolio),
3. Made sure that `'projects'` is inside the `INSTALLED_APPS` list in `settings.py`.

Here is `urls.py` that's inside rp-portfolio\personal_portfolio:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('projects/', include('projects.urls'))
]
```

Here is `urls.py` that's inside rp-portfolio\projects:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.project_index, name="project_index"),
    path("<int:pk>/", views.project_detail, name="project_detail"),
]
```

Comment: What's confusing you about the error? You don't have a path for "/", you just have one for "/projects".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('projects/', include('projects.urls')),
    path('', RedirectView.as_view(url='/projects/')),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

in urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('projects.urls'))
]
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

as you are seeking a path inside project your requested path must be this http://localhost:8000/projects/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```
in polls/urls.py
```

add this: `from django.conf.urls import url`

so it shold look like:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the URL picks up other words from the terminal.

**Example 1.0**

Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.

For instance in Example 1.0, instead of opening a link like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

The link will be `http://127.0.0.1:8000/Quit` since `/Quit` is not included as part of your code you will get the 404 error.

**Example 2.0**

```
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with 
CTRL-BREAK.
Not Found: /Quit
[27/May/2021 22:36:07] "GET /Quit HTTP/1.1" 404 2066
[27/May/2021 22:36:59] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5873
[27/May/2021 22:37:04] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5873
```

Hope you find this helpful.