# Why doesn't my Django app work, 404 Page not found

Tags: python, django

I know somebody has asked this question [this is the link to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55536646/how-to-fix-page-not-found-404-error-django-tried-these-url-patterns-the), but none of the solutions there worked for me so I had to open a new question. When I run my code I get this error message:

> Using the URLconf defined in storefront.urls, Django tried these URL
> patterns, in this order:
>
> admin/
>
> playground/
>
> The empty path didn’t match any of these.

here is my **storefront** ***urls.py***:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('playground/', include('playground.urls')),
]
```

and here is my **playground** ***urls.py***:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

# URL conf module
urlpatterns = [
    path('hello/', views.say_hello)
]
```

also here is my **playground** ***views.py***:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def say_hello(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello World')
```

Can somebody tell me what could be the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: How you define your urls.py this will never found /playground/ it should be `playground/hello/` then you can see the URLs will work properly. 
You need to adjust your URLs patterns depending on your needs.

Comment: I changed it to playground/hello/ and it still doesn't work.

Comment: what is the endpoint you are trying to access that is throwing the error, from the snippets you made available that looks like ```playground/hello/```. if this is not the case then you are accessing the wrong endpoint. add the complete url you are trying here for more context, and possibly add a screenshot of the error message title

Comment: this is the endpoint: http://127.0.0.1:8000/playground/hello/
But it gives me this error with any endpoint even when I start the server.

Comment: did you try rerunning the server or try in a different port?

Comment: Yes I tried python manage.py runserver 9000 but i was still the same

Comment: Seems like you are missing something which is a very tiny issue. To me seems you are 100% correct in your code and how you explain and define it. Make sure your URL doesn't have any `/` in front it should be exactly like how you mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely this should work, Everything seems to fine. Try restarting your server with another port and try in browser's incognito mode.

http://127.0.0.1:8000/playground/hello/

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to access django server url with an empty path.
Looking at your source code you have added url endpoints as follows:-
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
http://127.0.0.1:8000/playground/hello/
But you are trying to access http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Which will give you the error because in storefront/urls.py
you have not mentioned any url path as
path('/', include('hello.urls'))

"**/**" indicates the empty url to django server.
Please change your url to same and you will be able to access the path you want.

Else you can access the urls that i have mentioned in the line number 3,4.

Answer (score 1):

First of all let Django be aware of your playground app in the settings.py file, go to
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'playground',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
if this was already done, then enter this address it should work

http://127.0.0.1:8000/playground/hello/